# Ejercicio de arrays en javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Este problema me tira error y no se donde estoy fallando.

Necesitamos una función "masMenos" que reciba un array y devuelva otro con los siguientes tres números:

- en la primera posición, la fracción de números que son positivos
- en la segunda posición, la fracción de números que son cero
- en la última posición, la fracción de números que son negativos

Por ejemplo, masMenos([1, 2, 0, -1]) debería devolver [0.5, 0.25, 0.25], dado que hay 50% de positivos, 25% de ceros, y 25% de negativos.

```
function masMenos(numeros){

        var positivos = 0;
        var cero = 0;
        var negativos = 0;

        for (var i=0; i<numeros.lenght; i++){
             if (numeros > 0)
                positivos+1 }


            if (numeros < 0) {
              negativos+1 }

            if (numeros == 0) {
               cero+1 }


   var suma = positivos + negativos + cero;

   var porcentaje = [positivos / suma, negativos / suma, cero / suma]

   return porcentaje

}
```

Comment: Procura incluir el error que te tira. Copia y pega el mensaje de error completo.

Answer (score 4):

Tienes varios errores de sintaxis.  Debes asegurarte de abrir y cerrar las llaves `{}` correctamente en cada bloque.  Para la longitud del array necesitas usar `length`.  Para accesar los numeros del array necesitas especificar el indice con la variable `i`.  Quedaria asi:

```js
function masMenos(numeros){

        var positivos = 0;
        var cero = 0;
        var negativos = 0;

        for (var i=0; i<numeros.length; i++){
             if (numeros[i] > 0) {
                positivos+=1 }


            if (numeros[i] < 0) {
              negativos+=1 }

            if (numeros[i] == 0) {
               cero+=1 }
        }

   var suma = positivos + negativos + cero;

   var porcentaje = [positivos / suma, negativos / suma, cero / suma]

   return porcentaje

}

console.log(masMenos([1,2,0,-1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

tu error es que no accedes a la posicion del arreglo si no al arreglo completo puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
function masMenos(numeros){

        var positivos = 0;
        var cero = 0;
        var negativos = 0;

        for (var i=0; i<numeros.length; i++){
             if (numeros[i] > 0) {
                positivos+=1 }


            if (numeros[i] < 0) {
              negativos+=1 }

            if (numeros[i] == 0) {
               cero+=1 }
        }

   var suma = positivos + negativos + cero;

   var porcentaje = [positivos / suma, negativos / suma, cero / suma]

   return porcentaje

}

r = masMenos([1,2,0,-1]);

console.log(` positivos: ${r[0]} , negativos: ${r[1]}, ceros: ${r[2]} `);
```

si quieres hacerlo mas eficiente seria:

```js
    function masMenos(numeros) {
        // almacenara ceros,positivo,negativo 
        let num = [0,0,0];
        // longitud del arreglo
        let len = numeros.length;

        // loop
        for (let x of numeros) {
            if (x == 0) num[0]++;
            if (x > 0)  num[1]++;
            if (x < 0)  num[2]++;
        }

      // sacamos el porcentaje
      num[0] = (num[0]*100)/len;
      num[1] = (num[1]*100)/len;
      num[2] = (num[2]*100)/len;

      // retornamos el arreglo
      return num;
    }

    r = masMenos([1, 2, 0, -1]);
    console.log(`ceros: ${r[0]}% , positivos: ${r[1]}% , negativos: ${r[2]}%`);
```